# Git fetch fails when using from two different computers

Tags: git, fetch, atom-editor, antivirus

I have Atom 1.58.0 x64 installed on a Windows PC and a Mac. When either the PC or the Mac is able to push/pull to my GitHub repo, the other will not. On loading Atom, a message that my repo doesn't exist flashes on the screen and when I fetch, the error message is *fatal: protocol error: bad line length 2*.

I understand that this may be connected to the anti-virus program that my school requires. If I start over and clone the repo locally, I'm able to push/pull - until I do the same on the other computer. At which point, only the most recently cloned installation works. I would be very grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Do you push from one computer and then `push` does not work on the other computer or does `pull` not work?

Edit: also, are working on the same branch on both computers?

Comment: I'm only working with one repo and one branch. When one computer won't push/pull, I've started over with a new clone on the non-working computer - which works for that computer. But then attempts to pull from the other computer generate the error. I appreciate any thoughts!

Comment: Looks like implementing ssh key on both computers and then starting over on the out-of-date computer with a new clone solved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The message `protocol error: bad line length` means that something is tampering with your connection and corrupting the data.

This is very common with anti-virus and firewall programs, many of which perform TLS interception to scan for "threats".  Unfortunately, they also tend to break Git very frequently and often introduce security vulnerabilities.  Other types of TLS middleboxes, such as proxies, can also cause this.

Ideally you will remove this software from all systems, and on Windows, just use Windows Defender instead.  If you cannot do that, you'll need to turn off TLS interception, which may be specified as "scanning encrypted connections".  You can also switch to using SSH instead if that's an option.

Comment: Thank you. I set up SSH, but it did not have any impact on the problem. My school mandates Sophos for anti-virus. I have not found a way to add an exception for GitHub.

Comment: Hey! Looks like ssh DID work. After enabling ssh on both computers, deleting the out of date local repo and cloning it, push/pull is working on both computers. Thank you!